# SQL Aggregate Functions -- HAVING vs WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

**Context:** I'm fiddling with SQL in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) Postgres 9.6. I'm trying to apply aggregate functions to 2 columns in the outer query that are dependent on the existence of values from a subquery.

I'm having a hard time determining whether the query is correct using the WHERE clause instead of HAVING.The SQL executes but I'm not confident that it's generating the intended results.

**Question:** Can someone help me understand if this is the correct way to perform the aggregation? And if not how can I modify the query to get the intended results if including HAVING requires GROUPING BY `user_id` in the outer query which kinda defeats the purpose.

**Intended Results:** I want to count the number of actions a user takes before progressing to a new action. I only want to count the number of `Read Article` events if a user (`user_id`) made it to the next action (`View Product`) I'm going to use the aggregation to calculate some averages.

**Sample output:**
[image]

**Query:**

```
SELECT event_type as action_a,
       COUNT(event_type) as action_a_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as unique_users
FROM events 
WHERE event_type in ('Read Article')
AND user_id in 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) as user_id 
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type in ('View Product')
  )
GROUP BY event_type
```

Comment: You've not explained the *intended results* or provided sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data. It's difficult to say whether you're doing things correctly or not when you don't explain what you intend to do. You may be confusing some things, too. HAVING is usually used after aggregation with a WHERE, to further reduce the result set. Consider counting the number of orders for customers that have ordered a certain product in a time period (WHERE and GROUP BY) and then only seeing the ones that have purchased 100 or more (HAVING SUM() >= 100).

Comment: Side notes: **(1)** `event_type`  is 'Read Article', i.e. not null. So `COUNT(event_type)` is merely supposed to count rows rather than not null occurrences of `event_type`. Use `COUNT(*)` instead which is meant to do exactly this: count rows. **(2)** `DISTINCT` is not a function. So, `DISTINCT(user_id)`should be `DISTINCT user_id`. And anyway, in an `IN` clause you don't have to use `DISTINCT`. It is even recommended not to do this. Don't tell the DBMS how to do ist work, it suffices to say you want user IDs in that set: `AND user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM events ...`...

Comment: **(3)** And `user_id as user_id` is superfluous of course. **(4)** and `event_type in ('View Product')` can be written as `event_type = 'View Product'` as you probably know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is good. With `WHERE event_type = 'Read Article'` you filter events rows. Thus only those rows must be aggregated.

You could use `HAVING event_type = 'Read Article'` instead, because you are grouping by that column, too. That would mean you would first look up users for *all* rows and would aggregate over all desired user rows and only then dismiss undesired event_types. This would give the DBMS much more work to do.

Conclusion: Use `WHERE` to reduce the rows as soon as possible, so the DBMS can work on smaller data sets. This will Speed up your queries.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING and WHERE do appear to have overlap but there are differences, WHERE checks a row for equality whereas HAVING is used to check against aggregate sets, the most basic example would be finding duplicates in a table with a

```
SELECT column_name, count(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This query would need to count the rows before filtering, thus uses HAVING. In your case, filtering for equality using WHERE is fine because it only needs to take a single row into account.